# Setting fancy headers and footers in an environment

Tags: environments, fancyhdr, texlive-2021

I have a document style where environments set page headers and footers using the `fancyhdr` package and recently have noticed a change in how these behave. It seems the headers set in the beginning of an environment are now auto-reset when the environment ends. Looking at PDF files I have compiled from the same source up to December 2020, the headers used to stick until new ones were set explicitly.

An example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newenvironment{test}[1]{\rhead{#1}}{} % setting the header in beginning of environment
\begin{document}
\begin{test}{Test 1}
Text 1 (environment 1 starts)
\clearpage
Text 2 (environment 1 ends)
\end{test}
\clearpage
Text 3
\begin{test}{Test 2}
Text 4 (environment 2 starts)
\clearpage
Text 5 (environment 2 ends)
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

The result is that on the first page (where the first environment starts), the header is set as expected:
[image: header appears on first page]

On second page (where the first environment ends), the header is reset to the default blank:
[image: header does not appear on second page]

The same pattern continues on third and fourth page: start of the second environment sets the header for the third page, but end of the  second environment clears it again for the fourth page.

What could be the reason and how to fix this?

This is the version information for my setup:

```
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021/Cygwin)
kpathsea version 6.3.3
Copyright 2021 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.03
```

Comment: One can use \thispagestyle to change a single header.  Not sure if it will work inside an environment (all my latex-tools documents were lost with the latest MikTeX update).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `fancyhdr`version 3 indeed all `fancyhdr`definitions were global. I found that undesirable, because it made it impossible to change the definitions only inside an environment, as is usual with LaTeX definitions.
So in `fancyhdr`version 4 I changed this.

The problem with your example is that the environments ends too early. The environment should end after all the pages that need the local definition have been put out. In this case that can be easily accomplished by giving the `\clearpage`before the `\end{test}`including at the end of the document.

I am contemplating of adding an option to have a global redefinition if you desire that.

Here is your example with the `\clearpage`commands before the `\end{test}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newenvironment{test}[1]{\rhead{#1}}{} % setting the header in beginning of environment
\begin{document}
\begin{test}{Test 1}
Text 1 (environment 1 starts)
\clearpage
Text 2 (environment 1 ends)
\clearpage
\end{test}
Text 3
\begin{test}{Test 2}
Text 4 (environment 2 starts)
\clearpage
Text 5 (environment 2 ends)
\clearpage
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aha, this explains the situation and I can now update my styles to work as before. Thanks.

Comment: On second thought, while I can change my styles to restore the behavior that I want, perhaps some others can't extend the range of their environments like that and then an option to make the definitions global again would be useful indeed. (For all I know, I myself may become such an "other" in the next bigger report...)

Comment: In that case you can make the redefinition global with the following construct: `\newenvironment{test}[1]{{\globaldefs=1\rhead{#1}}}{}` The `\globaldefs=1` is a low-level TeX trick to make local changes into global ones. The extra pair of braces is necessary to prevent the `\globaldefs=1` to also affect the rest of the environment; now its effect is limited to the doubly-braced code.

Comment: And in these cases (making local changes to the page style I always recommend defining a new page style with `\fancypagestyle`; I think this usually is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, good to know.